# Positive solutions of a diophantine equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

When looking at the positive solutions on $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ of the equation:
$$ax+by=c$$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$

Granted that $g = gcd(a,b)$ divides c, we found that the inequality:

$$ab<gc$$

implies existence of a solution.

Is there an intuitive reason why for c large enough we have solution(s)?

Comment: Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem, case $n=2$.

Comment: Look at $ax+by=c$ as a line in ${\mathbb R}^2$. If $c$ is large, then there are more posibilities that a *positive integer point* is on the line.